# Solve Proxy error when making request from react app to ingress gateway

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have a working local REACT frontend instance secured with ssl (https://admin.im.co). I also have a working local ingress backend gateway secured with ssl (https://gate.im.co).

I have added the backend gateway address to the react package.json

```
"proxy" : "https://gate.im.co"
```

If I send login request through postman, it returns correct response, However, sending request via react gives an error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/login from admin.im.co to https://gate.im.co.
see https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (EAI_AGAIN)
```

NB: A while back it use to work fine but then there was a power surge and the server was switched off. Currently, I can't seem to be able to query backend via the proxy. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash to the end of the backend gateway URL in the React package.json file like this

```
"proxy" : "https://gate.im.co/"
```

It has worked for some who have encountered similar issues.